# viso2 "visual odometer got lost"

Tags: c++, camera, transform, opticalflow

hi i am having some problem with the viso2 package's stereo odometry,it gives me "visual odometer got lost" when i am trying to run the launch file.I am currently using 2 Ueye UI-1226LE - USB 2.0 Camera for the stereo odometry.Below are the error that it gives me.

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /dynparam_ubuntu_14461_8489014763432242877/auto_exposure
 * /dynparam_ubuntu_14461_8489014763432242877/frame_rate
 * /dynparam_ubuntu_14461_8489014763432242877/l_pixel_clock
 * /dynparam_ubuntu_14461_8489014763432242877/r_pixel_clock
 * /dynparam_ubuntu_14461_8489014763432242877/zoom
 * /kitty_stereo/stereo_image_proc/correlation_window_size
 * /kitty_stereo/stereo_image_proc/disparity_range
 * /kitty_stereo/stereo_image_proc/min_disparity
 * /kitty_stereo/stereo_image_proc/prefilter_cap
 * /kitty_stereo/stereo_image_proc/prefilter_size
 * /kitty_stereo/stereo_image_proc/speckle_range
 * /kitty_stereo/stereo_image_proc/speckle_size
 * /kitty_stereo/stereo_image_proc/texture_threshold
 * /kitty_stereo/stereo_image_proc/uniqueness_ratio
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /kitty_stereo/
    stereo_image_proc (stereo_image_proc/stereo_image_proc)
  /
    base_link_to_camera (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    dynparam_ubuntu_14461_8489014763432242877 (dynamic_reconfigure/dynparam)
    rosbag (rosbag/play)
    stereo_odometer (viso2_ros/stereo_odometer)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http:// localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[base_link_to_camera-1]: started with pid [14521]
process[rosbag-2]: started with pid [14539]
process[kitty_stereo/stereo_image_proc-3]: started with pid [14556]
process[stereo_odometer-4]: started with pid [14577]
[ INFO] [1390285927.188771517]: Subscribing to:
    * /kitty_stereo/left/image_rect
    * /kitty_stereo/right/image_rect
    * /kitty_stereo/left/camera_info
    * /kitty_stereo/right/camera_info
process[dynparam_ubuntu_14461_8489014763432242877-5]: started with pid [14602]
[ INFO] [1390285927.228780458]: Basic Odometer Settings:
  odom_frame_id      = /odom
  base_link_frame_id = /base_link
  publish_tf         = true
[ INFO] [1390285928.211526383, 1385798595.722205257]: Retrieving initial transform for /base_link to /camera.
[ INFO] [1390285928.211638745, 1385798595.722205257]: Initialized libviso2 stereo odometry with the following parameters:
Calibration parameters:
  f  = 1504.27
  cu = 188.791
  cv = 59.5449
Matcher parameters:
  nms_n                  = 3
  nms_tau                = 50
  match_binsize          = 50
  match_radius           = 200
  match_disp_tolerance   = 2
  outlier_disp_tolerance = 5
  outlier_flow_tolerance = 5
  multi_stage            = 1
  half_resolution        = 1
  refinement             = 1
Bucketing parameters:
  max_features  = 2
  bucket_width  = 50
  bucket_height = 50
Stereo odometry parameters:
  base             = 0.281359
  ransac_iters     = 200
  inlier_threshold = 1.5
  reweighting      = 1
  ref_frame_change_method = 0
  ref_frame_motion_threshold = 5
  ref_frame_inlier_threshold = 150
[ WARN] [1390285928.216198038, 1385798595.722205257]: Visual Odometer got lost!
[dynparam_ubuntu_14461_8489014763432242877-5] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/acsc/.ros/log/a56e242a-8245-11e3-bf8d-48022a9ad0c5/dynparam_ubuntu_14461_8489014763432242877-5*.log
[ WARN] [1390285929.245663614, 1385798596.751227928]: Visual Odometer got lost!
[ WARN] [1390285930.250121013, 1385798597.777895990]: Visual Odometer got lost!
[ WARN] [1390285931.248951670, 1385798598.781152478]: Visual Odometer got lost!
[ WARN] [1390285932.318369814, 1385798599.847003310]: Visual Odometer got lost!
[ WARN] [1390285933.353832605, 1385798600.882260371]: Visual Odometer got lost!
[ WARN] [1390285934.417855748, 1385798601.942012156]: Visual Odometer got lost!
[ WARN] [1390285935.456077597, 1385798602.975817837]: Visual Odometer got lost!
[ WARN] [1390285936.456490832, 1385798603.986285772]: Visual Odometer got lost!
[ WARN] [1390285937.527047462, 1385798605.048900696]: Visual Odometer got lost!
[ WARN] [1390285938.559818811, 1385798606.088479625]: Visual Odometer got lost!
[ WARN] [1390285939.594780232, 1385798607.122738611]: Visual Odometer got lost!
```

and this is the launch file i am currently using

```
<launch>

    <!-- Arguments -->
    <arg name="kitty_01" default="/home/acsc/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/kitti_01.bag"/> <!-- Your bagfile here -->
    <arg name="camera" default="/kitty_stereo" /> <!-- The namespace where images are published -->
    <arg name="disparity_params" default="/home/acsc/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/disparity_params.yaml"/> <!-- Camera calibration parameters -->

    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_camera" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /camera 100 " />

    <!-- Run the rosbag -->
    <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="--clock $(arg kitty_01)"/>

    <!-- Run the ROS package stereo_image_proc -->
    <group ns="$(arg camera)" >
        <node pkg="stereo_image_proc" type="stereo_image_proc" name="stereo_image_proc">
            <rosparam file="$(arg disparity_params)"/>
        </node>
    </group>

    <!-- Run the viso2_ros package -->
    <node pkg="viso2_ros" type="stereo_odometer" name="stereo_odometer" output="screen">
        <remap from="stereo" to="$(arg camera)"/>
        <remap from="image" to="image_rect"/>
    </node>
<node name="$(anon dynparam)" pkg="dynamic_reconfigure" type="dynparam" args="set_from_parameters camera">
 <param name="zoom" value="2"/>
 <param name="l_pixel_clock" value="20"/>
 <param name="r_pixel_clock" value="20"/>
 <param name="auto_exposure" value="true"/>
 <param name="frame_rate" value="30"/>
</node>


</launch>
```

Comment: I see no evidence whatsoever that this statement is relevant to stackoverflow.

Comment: hi i am just wondering if anyone here can help me with my problem cause i do not know where else to turn to.thanks for the help